Kleartouch.MediaPlayer.WinUI throw 'The specific device interface or feature level is not supported on this system'
I have app in WinUI 3 and .Net Core and I display Video mp4 in MediaPlayer.
when I run my app in spesific computer, The video is not loaded and I get exception and my app crash.
the exception is : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The spesific device interface or feature level is not supported on this system.'
the exception throw from this line:
MediaPlayerElement.SetMedisPlayer(mediaPlayer);
SetMedisPlayer is from Kleartouch.MediaPlayer.WinUI library.
in stackTrace I see also "at DirectN.HRESULT.ThrowOnError(...) at DirectN.D3D11Functions.D3D11CreateDevice(...)..."
I try check windows version and is windows 10 Home 22H2
Build version 19045.4894
I also try check the version of DirectX and is 12
I don't success to check the 'Feature Levels' of DirectX - I don't know if it helpful.
what can I do?

It might be better if you ask this question to the library owner in the repo.

You shouldn't use that library now that winui3 supports MediaPlayerElement

I try change to  MediaPlayerElement of WinUI3 but I get exception when I create it from stream. In this link my question you can help me?
link
